# How to change only some of the navbar link colors?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, navbar

I'm building a site that has half of the navbar links in black, and half in white. I have:

```
@navbar-default-link-color: #fcfcfc;
```

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to override the link color for the other half of the navbar. I've tried things I found googling like:

```
.navbar-default > .navbar-nav > .dark > a:link {
  color: #171b1e !important;
}
```

and just

```
.dark {
  @navbar-default-link-color: @brand-primary;
}
```

HTML example:

```
<li class="dark">
  <a href="https://dribbble.com" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

I've also tried id's instead of classes. Nothing I've tried will override the link color. I did read something about changing each individual navbar link using each #menu-item but I'm at a loss on how to actually get the #menu-item values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know whether the correct CSS is being applied without looking at the browser inspector, but this should work:

If you applying dark to the `<li>` element, you mostly likely need to apply it directly to the `<a>` element because it has default colors applied to it.

```
.dark > a {
  color: @brand-primary;
}
```

If that does not work, try to implement `!important`. That will force it to use the correct color:

```
.dark > a {
  color: @brand-primary !important;
}
```

You could also simply apply colors to the `<a>` element. In that case:

```
a.dark {
  color: @brand-primary !important;
}
```

and apply it on `<a>`

```
<li>
  <a class="dark">
    Link Text
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! The third way worked (a.dark). However, this removes my hover color from the links. How do I force it back?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a gradient  for the navbar ..but it will be gradual color transition.

Edit: just use navbar and not navbar-default or inverse styling ..you could then manually write css like

```
  .navbar {
            background: #e0e0e0;

        .navitem {
               background: #ffffff;
  }
        .navitem2 {
               background: #ffffff;
  }
  }
```